# Create DIV in java

Tags: java, gwt

How do I create a DIV programatically in Java to that will render a DIV that looks like this:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="595" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

For some reason, I need to do it in Java instead of the Errai-UI template; for reason that it seems that it gets removed when transitioning in pages.

Anyway, should I use DivElement or someting else? The idea is that I should be able to create this on the Java code and insert it into a SimplePanel of some sort...

Comment: can you not use `HTML` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the HTML widget:

```
HTML html = new HTML("<div class='fb-like-box' data-href='http://www.facebook.com/platform' data-width='595' data-show-faces='true' data-stream='true' data-header='true'></div>");

panel.add(html);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with **[SafeHtml](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtml.html)(prevents script injections)** in GWT.

```
String s = "<div>some html goes here</div>";
SafeHtml safeHtml = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(s);

And then Prepare HTML with that


HTML dynamicHTml = new HTML(safeHtml);
```

*SafeHtml evaluates the string as HTML in a browser will not result in script execution.*

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, a `FlowPanel` will render a `div` element by default. You could set arbitrary `data` attributes on it like:

```
FlowPanel div = new FlowPanel();
div.getElement().setAttribute("data-myattr", "somevalue");
```